# Approval email flow is not honored in logic apps

Tags: azure, sharepoint-online, azure-logic-apps

It looks little weird. The approval email is however received.

My Logic App has a number of actions to collect & process the data from SharePoint Online. All actions with regards to the processing are working as expected. Even the Approval step is getting executed

However, the "Send Approval Email" action does not wait for a response.

Any help here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3rd party mail filters (like G Suite and Mimecast) will autoselect the User options in 'Send email with options' action. For that reason, please set Show HTML confirmation dialog to Yes in order to avoid this problem related to the functionality.

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365/